# What are twitter indices?

Tags: api, twitter

on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

I found **indices = The character positions the media was extracted from**

But I just dont understand what this means...

Thanks for your answer

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, an entity is like the mentions of other users in a tweet, so when you get the entity, that `indice` is telling you the position in the `tweet (string)` where that `entity (mention)` is.